# Simple proxy authentication using squid

Tags: squid

I'm trying to configure squid to require authentication.

I've got squid to work without authentication, than I

```
 htpasswd -c /etc/squid3/passwd foo
```

after this, I've replaced

```
http_access allow all
```

with

```
acl foo proxy_auth REQUIRED    
http_access allow foo
http_access deny all
```

and added

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/passwd
auth_param basic credentialsttl 30 minutes
auth_param basic casesensitive on
```

to `/etc/squid3/squid.conf`.

Now, when I do `service squid3 restart`, I get

```
stop: Unknown instance:
squid3 start/running, process 12256
```

when I run `ps aux` I can't find squid amonst processes running and the server cannot be connected to.

Why isn't this working?

**UPDATE**

`squid3 -d 10` shows:

```
Can't use proxy auth because no authentication schemes are fully configured.
FATAL: ERROR: Invalid ACL: acl foo proxy_auth REQUIRED
```

Comment: did you check squid's log files?

Comment: where are those located?

Comment: not sure, but most likely in /var/log. Otherwise, run squid in debug mode `squid3 -d 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your squid authentication configuration is missing `authentication helpers`, such as `ncsa_auth`. For step by step setup you might need to follow [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-squid-proxy-server-authentication.html).

Comment: the problem was that I've put the auth_param lines at the end of configuration file, while they should be before the `acl foo proxy_auth....` . Thanks for the help!