# Squid 4.2 - Different outbound IP for each client/user

Tags: proxy, ip, squid, ip-forwarding

I have been playing with a few different pieces of forward proxy software, primarily CCProxy and Squid Proxy/Cache. What I have is a dedicated server with a single NIC with multiple IPs assigned to it. One IP is static and the rest are dynamic. The static IP acts as a primary address, which is how I access my proxy server, the others are dynamic ip addresses for web scraping and other tasks. I have created a proxy in CCProxy and it allows you to link a user to a specific outbound ip address, this is really useful for what I am doing, allowing me to assign different tasks to different IPs.

So what I was wondering if this was possible to do in Squid Proxy?

I love how customisable Squid is but I really could do with this feature.

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option to do this is [`tcp_outgoing_address`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/tcp_outgoing_address/):

> Allows you to map requests to different outgoing IP addresses based
>   on the username or source address of the user making the request.

"outgoing IP address" really means "source IP". Now you can choose an [acl](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/) to distinguish your user by any available mean, client's IP (`acl ... src ...`), [simple proxy authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/479493/simple-proxy-authentication-using-squid) ([`auth_param`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/auth_param/) + [`basic_ncsa_auth`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/squid/basic_ncsa_auth.8.en.html)) etc.

Example adapted from documentation, using source IP as selector, where the squid server would be owning various IPs in the `192.0.2.0/24` LAN with its primary IP `192.0.2.1`. Adding this to the typical sample `squid.conf`:

```
acl allowed_clients src 198.51.100.0/24
http_access allow allowed_clients

acl dedicated_client1 src 198.51.100.174
tcp_outgoing_address 192.0.2.174 dedicated_client1
tcp_outgoing_address 192.0.2.10 allowed_clients
tcp_outgoing_address 192.0.2.5
```

will allow clients from `allowed_clients`, and have them use outgoing IP `192.0.2.10`, except for client from `198.51.100.174` which will get `192.0.2.174`. Any other client configured elsewhere than in this example would use `192.0.2.5` and the server's primary IP will never be used.